# This parallelized sum program, using divide-and-conquer, does not terminate

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I am trying to implement a simple parallel sum of list in Scala. This one below uses divide-and-conquer recursively, but it turns out the program does not terminate. Where is the problem? What is the right way to do this computing?

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, ExecutorService, Executors, Future}

val es=Executors.newWorkStealingPool()

def sumP(ints: IndexedSeq[Int]): Int = {if (ints.size <= 1)
  ints.headOption getOrElse 0 else {
  val (l, r) = ints.splitAt(ints.length / 2)
  val fut_l = es.submit(new Callable[Int] {
    override def call = sumP(l)
  })
  val fut_r = es.submit(new Callable[Int]  {
    override def call = sumP(r)
  })
  fut_l.get() + fut_r.get()
}}
println("result is here: ")
val res=sumP(1 to 4000000)
```

Comment: The code runs (and terminates) for me. The formatting is almost unreadable but, fortunately, the compiler doesn't mind.

Comment: It seems that if the range is a bit larger (see edits), the program does not terminate, or at least, does not terminate in a reasonable time bound. So I guess that the program may have some internal issue?

Comment: The overhead for thread creation/management is swamping any tiny gains from parallelization.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks. Then, how would you do a parallel divide-and-conquer for computing the sum?

Comment: You've done it. That's what your code does. It's just not efficient for large numbers. The whole point of parallel computation is to maximize your computer's resources. How many cores/CPUs does your computer have? There's little point in spawning more threads than CPUs. When threads outnumber CPUs then thread management starts to crowd out the actual work (sums) being done.

Comment: @jwvh I see. It is actually a very good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be much faster.

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, Executors}

val es=Executors.newWorkStealingPool()

def sumP(ints: IndexedSeq[Int], threadLimit: Int = 8): Int = {
  if (ints.size < 5 || threadLimit < 2) ints.sum
  else {
    val (l, r) = ints.splitAt(ints.length / 2)
    es.submit(new Callable[Int] {override def call = sumP(l, threadLimit/2)})
      .get() +
     es.submit(new Callable[Int] {override def call = sumP(r, threadLimit/2)})
       .get()
  }
}
sumP(1 to 40000)  //res0: Int = 800020000
```

Pretty much the same as your code but with the amount of parallelization, i.e. thread count, limited. (The code is also easier to look at.)